# How to get all values of a nested div

Tags: python, html

I'd like to take all the values of a nested div.

```
<div class="upcoming-events__event  js-event-filter" data-eventtype="Mission Day" data-region="AMER" data-eventdate="2019-07-13" data-latlon="40.167207,-105.101928" data-distance="8693671.480264762" style="display: block;">
                    <a href="http://events.ingress.com/MissionDay/Longmont2019" class="upcoming-events__event-link">
                        <img src="/assets/img/events/md-2019-7-longmontcousa.jpg" class="upcoming-events__image">
                        <div class="upcoming-events__content">
                            <img src="/assets/img/missionday.png" class="event-icon">
                            <div class="upcoming-events__date">Jul 13, 2019</div>
                            <div class="upcoming-events__location">Longmont, CO, USA</div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

for each class upcoming-events__event I'd like to print

upcoming-events__location, upcoming-events__date.
For more information: upcoming-events__event-link

Answer (score 0):

Using bs4, you can get the text.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''<div class="upcoming-events__event  js-event-filter" data-eventtype="Mission Day" data-region="AMER" data-eventdate="2019-07-13" data-latlon="40.167207,-105.101928" data-distance="8693671.480264762" style="display: block;">
                    <a href="http://events.ingress.com/MissionDay/Longmont2019" class="upcoming-events__event-link">
                        <img src="/assets/img/events/md-2019-7-longmontcousa.jpg" class="upcoming-events__image">
                        <div class="upcoming-events__content">
                            <img src="/assets/img/missionday.png" class="event-icon">
                            <div class="upcoming-events__date">Jul 13, 2019</div>
                            <div class="upcoming-events__location">Longmont, CO, USA</div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
for i in (soup.select('.upcoming-events__event')):
    location=i.select('.upcoming-events__location')[0].string
    date=i.select('.upcoming-events__date')[0].string
    link=i.select('.upcoming-events__event-link')[0].get('href')
    print(f'{location}, {date}\nFor more info :{link}')
```

Comment: Can I put everything in a string and then print the string?